# How to handle concurrent requests?

Tags: asp.net

There is CRUD for working with ads

```
public class Ad
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Each user has a limit - you can add no more than 10 ads. Before creating an ad, the number of existing ads is checked.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateAd([FromBody] CreateAdRequest request)
{
    var adCount = _context.Ads.Count();

    if (adCount >= 10)
    {
        return BadRequest("Ad limit is exceeded");
    }
    
    ...
}
```

But for example, if 100 concurrent requests arrive, the limit will be exceeded and there will be more than 10 ads in the database.

I think I should use transactions and isolation levels, can you explain how to do this

Comment: Might be a good time to use a stored procedure and have your database check if the request limit has been reached for the day, and if so, have it return a value indicating such else return something indicating the record was stored.

Comment: But your count is going to be based on the current user id. I fail to see how one user can or ever will create more then 1, let alone 100 requests. Since each user is only allowed 10 items, and not the total of all combined users, then I doubt this will be an issue.  You need to get a count of the current users' items, not the total overall count. Now, perhaps only 10 in total are allowed for all combined users, and if that is the case, then you want to start a transaction for the adding of a item and bail out of that transaction if the count exceeds 10.